# Using AWT in IntelliJ Idea's GUI Designer?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, intellij-idea, awt

I've been using IntelliJ Idea's GUI builder recently (I'm new to java) and I want to know if it's possible to use AWT components rather than Swing ones.

Would love a guide/tutorial to get me started as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: IDEA GUI designer supports only Swing, it will not work with AWT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to know if it's possible to use AWT components rather than
>   Swing ones.

yes with real reasons to creating custom Components based on

- OpenGL/CL
- CAD/CAM
- 3D animations
- media player
- custom explorer for Html4/5

> Would love a guide/tutorial to get me started as well.

Java AWT is outdated and from year 2002/3 replaced with Swing

Comment: I'm currently doing an outdated class that is teaching AWT and not Swing components, I've asked the professor and he's claimed it's outside of his hands.

Any way to get AWT components in the gui builder palette in IntelliJ Idea?

Comment: by default is there way, part of methods from Swing is implemented in prehistoric AWT Components too, create a GUI in Swing and to remove all J (e.g. from JTextField to TextField), no idea if  AWT Components are presented in the palette (do not use this GUI Builer), mabye will be required to write thisr code by your hands (never tried to use any GUI-Builed for create a GUi in Java)